# BigQuery: Selecting the 2nd largest for each user_id

Tags: google-bigquery

Table:

```
    | User_ID |  Red | Blue | Green |  Rating |
    |   a     |   23 |  33  |   42  |    99   |
    |   a     |   56 |  45  |   62  |    45   |
    |   a     |   23 |  49  |   28  |    67   |
    |   b     |   39 |  59  |   10  |    87   |
    |   b     |   18 |  28  |   59  |    38   |
    |   b     |   40 |  50  |   38  |    94   |
```

The schema looks something like this. With Red, Blue and Green being RGB numbers. Rating being how much each user likes the colour.

I need help in 3 queries:

1. Identify each users' favourite colour (a: row 1, b: row 6)
2. Identify each users' second favourite colour (a: row 3, b: row 4)
3. The sum of ratings for the top 2 favourite colours of each user.

Thanks!

//Edit:

Tried the following query:

```
    SELECT distinct(User_ID), Red, Blue, Green, Rating 
    FROM `test_colour` 
    WHERE Rating = (SELECT MAX(RATING) FROM `test_colour` )
    Group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

The above only returns the highest rated row

```
    SELECT distinct(User_ID), Red, Blue, Green, MAX(Rating)
    FROM `test_colour` 
    Group by 1,2,3,4
```

The above returns all rows..

Comment: that is extremely simple query! have you tried at least something here? show us and we will help and will not feel like you are outsourcing your homework :o)

Comment: Hey, i've edited my response to show what i've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and gives you all 3 questions in one shot!

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' User_ID, 23 Red, 33 Blue, 42 Green, 99 Rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 56, 45, 62, 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 23, 49, 28, 67 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 39, 59, 10, 87 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 18, 28, 59, 38 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 40, 50, 38, 94 
)
SELECT User_ID, 
  favorites[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] first, 
  favorites[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] second,
  favorites[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].Rating + favorites[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].Rating TotalRating
FROM (
  SELECT User_ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Red, Blue, Green, Rating) ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 2) favorites
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY User_ID
)
```

Can be good exercise for you to walk through it and understand how it works :o)

Result of above example is as below

```
Row User_ID first.Red   first.Blue  first.Green first.Rating    second.Red  second.Blue second.Green    second.Rating   TotalRating  
1   a       23          33          42          99              23          49          28              67              166  
2   b       40          50          38          94              39          59          10              87              181
```